# What can go wrong if I include two categorical variables and intercept in linear regression?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

What can go wrong if I include two categorical variables and intercept in linear regression?

With:

```
y~x1+x2
```

Both `x1` and `x2` are categorical variables, lets say `x1` has 3 levels, `x2` has 2 levels.

I encoded them as the following:

`x1` corresponds to a design matrix of three columns, each column has 0-1 values indicating whether the observation belong to that level or not.

`x2` corresponds to a design matrix of two columns, each column has 0-1 values indicating whether the observation belong to that level or not.

I wanted the create a case which shows "multi-collinearity".

But both linear regressions seem to work fine below.

---

```
x1=factor(rep(1:3, 100))
x2=factor(rep(1:2, 150))

y=rnorm(300)

summary(lm(y~x1+x2+1))
summary(lm(y~x1+x2-1))
```

Comment: multicollinearity is what you get when two or more predictors are highly correlated with each other, but it appears you are generating variables which are not correlated at all.

Comment: But if we put a design matrix for categorical variable and an intercept together, the combined design matrix will be of reduced rank, i.e. rank-difficient. Am I right?

Comment: R has outsmarted you :), it treats the two regressions differently.  In the first case, it takes the first factor and re-frames it as a smaller number of factors, each representing the difference between a level and the first level (so there are 2 coefficients to estimate in your case instead of 3.)  It then does the same for the second.  Hence you get an intercept and 3 total coefficients.  In the second case, it knows there isn't an intercept, so it doesn't re-frame the first factor, instead leaving it as is.  It still re-frames the second factor, though, to avoid the multicollinearity.

Comment: @jbowman, that's a great catch, & I think, exactly the answer to this question. Why don't you turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: @gung - thanks for the suggestion, I couldn't think of a good reason why not, so I did :)

Answer (score 6):

When setting up the two regressions, R treats them differently. In the first (with intercept) case, it takes the first factor and re-frames it as a smaller number of factors, each representing the difference between a level and the first level (so there are 2 coefficients to estimate in your case instead of 3.)  This avoids the multicollinearity that would be caused by the "full" representation + an intercept.  It then does the same for the second. Hence you get an intercept and 3 total coefficients.

In the second case, it knows there isn't an intercept, so it doesn't re-frame the first factor, instead leaving it as is.  It still re-frames the second factor, though, to avoid the multicollinearity.

Here's your example; we can look at the coefficient values to see what's happening:

```
x1=factor(rep(1:3, 100))
x2=factor(rep(1:2, 150))
y=rnorm(300)

summary(lm(y~x1+x2+1))
 ... stuff ... 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.13537    0.11742   1.153   0.2499  
x12         -0.20787    0.14381  -1.445   0.1494  
x13         -0.28883    0.14381  -2.008   0.0455 *
x22          0.05656    0.11742   0.482   0.6304  
---

summary(lm(y~x1+x2-1))
 ... stuff removed ...

Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
x11  0.13537    0.11742   1.153    0.250
x12 -0.07250    0.11742  -0.617    0.537
x13 -0.15346    0.11742  -1.307    0.192
x22  0.05656    0.11742   0.482    0.630
```

You can see that the `Intercept` in the first regression has the same value as `x11` in the second.  `x12` in the first equals `x12-x11` in the second, and `x13` in the first equals `x13-x11` in the second, both as a consequence of representing the factors as differences in the first regression.  `x22` is the same in both, because including all the levels of the second factor will result in multicollinearity in both regressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot jbowman. I still don't understand this one "It still re-frames the second factor, though, to avoid the multicollinearity." I thought x2 doesn't need to reframed and should be fine, right?

Comment: So the intercept "(Intercept)  0.13537" in case 1 has both x11 and x21 elements in it, because x2 also got reframed? Thank you!

Comment: If you have a factor with two levels, you can think of the regression as being run with two 0-1 dummy variables, one for each level - let's call them z1 and z2.  Unfortunately, if you add the two dummy variables, you get a vector of all ones, which is the same as the intercept vector - so you have multicollinearity.  What R does is create a single dummy equal to z1 - z2 and includes the intercept in the regression.  The coefficient of the intercept (in the one-factor example) then becomes that of z1 and the coefficient of the single dummy is the difference between those of z1 and z2.

Comment: (+1) This is good to know. One question: do you know why the standard errors for the `x12` and `x13` different in the two models? It seems that the models, as you've described them, are mathematically equivalent so I'm not sure why the precision of the estimates of the mean of `y|x1=2` and `y|x1=3` would differ in the two models. Any ideas?

Comment: @Macro - the `x12` and `x13` in the first model are the same as `x12 - x11` and `x13 - x11` in the second; it would be nice if R would make explicit in the output that the variables are not the same across the two formulations, although the overall model is mathematically equivalent as you say.

Comment: @jbowman, yes I understand how the two models correspond to each other. My question that, since both model estimates of the conditional expectations of `y` are identical, why are their standard errors different? That is, if you compute the estimated conditional expectatin of `y|x1=2` in both models (by using the appropriate contrast) you get different standard errors for that estimate, despite the fact that the estimates are always identical.

Comment: @Macro - sorry for the delay responding, been very busy.  I have to admit your discovery puzzles me.  I also see the $R^2$ of the two models are different, although the standard error of the residuals is the same; I assume this is a no-intercept effect, and I assume, without any actual justification, that the lack of intercept accounts for what you're seeing - although why that should be isn't clear to me.