# OLS regression - Create a map from categorical location-related variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, spatial, statsmodels

With multiple linear regression in Python/statsmodels I would like to analyze quote data from the last 10 years as a hedonic price regression. The dependent and independent variables are given in the code below.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

md = smf.ols('system_price ~ system_capacity + module_rating + module_index_calc + inverter_index_calc + C(battery_inclusive, Treatment(reference="Nein")) + C(inverter_dc_optimization, Treatment(reference="No")) + C(installation_full, Treatment(reference="No")) + C(installation_scaffold, Treatment(reference="No")) + C(installation_ac, Treatment(reference="No")) + C(installation_elevation, Treatment(reference="No")) + C(zipcode_2digit)', data_original)

mdf = md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

In this example, I deleted location-related variables (e.g., wages, income levels,...) but added the zipcode_2digit as categorical variable for location-effects zipcode_2digit (99 elements).

I want to create a map that shows the regional price differences. For this, I took the estimates for the zip codes and plotted them on a shapefile.

[image: Estimates for C(zipcode_2digit, white=low, blue=high]

The idea is to capture price differences due to different system characteristics as well as time differences (inverter and module price index) in the regression estimates and to represent the location-related effects only by one variable (zipcode_2digit), which I can use for the illustration of the regional differences.

**Q1:** Is this a valid approach?

**Q2:** Do I have to take care of possible insignificant elements of C(zipcode_2digit) (cf. Figure below)?

**Q3:** The reference is zipcode "01". How can I get an estimate for this element to add to the map? Remove the intercept?

[image: Exemplary OLS regression results]

Comment: For Q3, the intercept *is* the estimate for the reference zipcode. Removing the intercept will produce a regression with a separate estimate for each zipcode.

Comment: So, do you would suggest to remove the intercept? If I do that, however, I still don't get an estimate for zip01, because otherwise there would be problems with collinearity, right?

Any suggestions on the other two questions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how some of this works in Python, but [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32241/what-can-go-wrong-if-i-include-two-categorical-variables-and-intercept-in-linear) may help